# Increase all cells value that contains number and text

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I'm trying to build a macro that can search for cells with any value in and increase the numbers inside them by one.

all my cells have a text and numbers for e.g. ( Movie 1 , Movie 2 , Car ) 
each cell contains a name and a number .. the name might be one or two words or more.. the number is not always at the end and it's usually from 0 to 200 but not all of the cells have numbers.

Those cells are all over the sheet and I want the macro to search for anything that has value in it and separate the numbers from texts then increase the numbers by one.

after hours of trial and error I reached to this code :

```
 Sub IncreaseCellValue()
    Dim value As Variant

    'Add 1 to the existing cell value

    If IsNumeric(Range("A1").value) Then
       Range("A1").value = Range("A1") + 1
    Else
       value = Split(Range("A1").value, " ")
       Range("A1").value = value(0) & " " & (CInt(value(1)) + 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem now is this code can only be applied to one specified cell.

Comment: I'd check if its numeric also on your else statement or you only have 1 word and 1 number separated by " " only?

Comment: Use something like ....  for each xCel in Range("younameit").Cells     to broaden to multiple cells

Comment: each cell contains a name and a number .. the name might be one or two words or more.. the number is always at the end and it's usually from 0 to 200

Comment: Added .. but not all of the cells have numbers BTW.

Comment: first I'm sorry the numbers aren't always at the end it's either at the end or at the beginning.  and yes that's my problem I wan't the code to search and apply on any number in a cell that contains texts and numbers without touching the empty ones or any cell with text only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since working directly with excel cells would slow down your executing time (when there are large number of cells to check), working with an array would be the key:

```
Option Explicit
Sub IncreaseCellValue()

    Dim arr As Variant
    'This will hold your whole worksheet. Change the sheet name
    arr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").UsedRange.Value

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr) 'for every row
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2) 'for every column
            Select Case True
                Case arr(i, j) = vbNullString
                Case arr(i, j) Like "*MyWord*" 'beware Like is Case Sensitive
                Case Else
                    arr(i, j) = AddOne(arr(i, j))
            End Select
        Next j
    Next i

    'Paste you array back to the worksheet
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").UsedRange.Value = arr

    'Note this will paste only values, so if you have formulas they will disappear

End Sub
Private Function AddOne(Value As Variant) As Variant

    Dim MySplit As Variant
    MySplit = Split(Value, " ")
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(MySplit) To UBound(MySplit)
        If IsNumeric(MySplit(i)) Then
            AddOne = AddOne & " " & MySplit(i) + 1
        Else
            AddOne = AddOne & " " & MySplit(i)
        End If
    Next i
    AddOne = Trim(AddOne)

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response ..The code didn't work. I got  Runtime Error 9 "subscript out of range" on Line 16

Comment: I don't have formulas and nothing complicated just test values ( Multi texts ) with numbers in them ( one number )

Comment: @ThamerAlfuraiji what is the value for `value(1)` on that line when the error shows?

Comment: I didn't get your question .. sorry I'm still a beginner in this.

Comment: Press ctrl + g, this will open the inmediate window on your screen. When the error pops, click on debug and then on that window type `? value(1)` it will return the value. What is it?

Comment: if you mean the watch window then value is 19.

Comment: @ThamerAlfuraiji try the edit see if it works. Now it is taking always the last part of the cell (which is a value if there is one as per your comments).

Comment: Ok, the code worked but in the wrong way .. first I'm sorry the numbers aren't always at the end it's either at the end or at the beginning .. second thing is the code deleted part of the text for example "Movie 76" became " vie 7677 " third problem the code is adding number 1 in all empty cells.

Comment: @ThamerAlfuraiji ok this should now handle everything, if there is a number it will be increased by 1.

Comment: IT WORKED !!!! Thank you so so much. 

another thing though if I want it to skip a cell with a certain word is that possible?

Comment: @ThamerAlfuraiji there you go, the last edit. Notice that I've added the  `Select Case` statement so you can skip as many words as you need with `Like` or `=`